# Did the play “Prometheus the Fire-Bringer” provide an aetiology for a festival honouring Prometheus?

Tags: greek-language, aeschylus, prometheus-the-fire-bringer

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_the_Fire-Bringer) on the lost play *Prometheus the Fire-Bringer* attributed to Aeschylus tells us:

> Finally, Athenaeus wrote of a contemporary Athenian festival dedicated to Prometheus:
>
> > Aeschylus clearly states in the *Unbound* that in honor of Prometheus we place a garland on the head as recompense of his bondage.<sup>[citation needed]</sup>
>
> Some scholars have taken this to mean that in the *Unbound*, Prometheus prophesies that eventually (in the *Fire-Bringer*), Zeus would reconcile with him, and institute some kind of festival in his honor. Given the title of the play, and considering that Aeschylus’ *Oresteia* provides an aetiology for Athens’s Areopagus, it has been suggested that *Prometheus the Fire-Bringer* concludes with providing an aetiology for a yearly Athenian torch race honoring the Titan.

The quoted passage from Athenaeus is this:

> Aeschylus also, in his Prometheus Unbound, says distinctly—
>
> > And therefore we, in honour of Prometheus,
> > Place garlands on our heads, a poor atonement
> > For the sad chains with which his limbs were bound.
>
> <sub>Athenaeus of Naucratis (c. 200). [*The Deipnosophists* 15.16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prometheus_the_Fire-Bringer). Translated by C. D. Yonge (1854). London: Henry G. Bohn.</sub>

However, there is no mention of a festival in Athenaeus. Who were the scholars who thought that there was an Athenian festival dedicated to Prometheus, for which *Prometheus the Fire-Bringer* provided an aetiology, and what were their arguments?